# Intellisense from _references.js in js files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

I get JS intellisese for all the files referenced in _references.js which is all great and good.

However, this only occurs in my index.html (presumably because I directly reference the files there). How do I get this intellisense in a .js file?

Could anyone please help me out here? It's really annoying and I've tried searching around myself with no success!

Comment: Looks like it isn't picking _references.js up. Is your _references.js in the `/Scripts` folder as describe at http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs?

Comment: @Rhumborl
Sure it is!
Like I said - it displays intellisense in my index.html (that references _references.js) but not in the .js files which obviously don't reference it.